# Accessing propertis of OneToOneFiled in the Same model

Tags: python, django, one-to-one

In the below example I'm trying to make default amount on the receipt the total method of related model bill. Django throws an error. Is there a way to do this?

```
class Bill(models.Model):
    amount1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 11, decimal_places = 2, default=0)
    amount2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 11, decimal_places = 2, default=0)

    def total_amount(self):
        return (self.amount1+self.amount2)



class Receipt(models.Model):
    bill = models.OneToOneField(Bill, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 11, decimal_places = 2, default=bill.total)
```

Comment: What was the error ?

Comment: OneToOneFiled has no attribute total was the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in the model definition - it simply does not make sense to do so. Defaults are applied when the model is instantiated, so there wouldn't even be a bill to have a total at that point even if you could access an instance value from a class variable.

Do this in the save method, or in the form/view that creates the receipt.